# Bigquery Terraform Schedule queries deployment error

Tags: google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Below is code from my Bigquery terraform main.tf file

```
    resource "google_bigquery_data_transfer_config" "config_queries" {
  for_each = fileset("${path.module}/scheduled_queries", "*.sql")
  depends_on = [google_bigquery_table.tables]
  data_source_id = "scheduled_queries"
  location=var.location
  destination_dataset_id=google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.dataset_id
  display_name = "config_queries_${substr(each.value, 0, length(each.value) -4)}"
  schedule = "every 4 hours "
 params = {
    destination_table_name_template = substr(each.value,0,length(each.value) -4)
    write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
    query = file("${path.module}/scheduled_queries/${each.value}")
  }
}
```

I am getting below error:

│ Error: Error creating Config: googleapi: Error 404: Requested entity was not found.

The same code is working fine if running sql files individually.
Any suggestions

Comment: This usually happens when the account you are using wont have access to the resource. Can you confirm if the project exists and have a valid billable account. Also, that's the only error raised? what is the output of "terraform plan"?? are you able to generate the execution plan without issues??

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-datatransfer/issues/21   ...this link solution worked for me

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your issue. To also help future users in the community, the solution was the comment provided by paslandu? Can you detail it? you can respond your own question too and i will thumb up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will leave this community answer for visibility. Please feel free to update if it not reflect the actual answer. This is the original response found in the [link](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-datatransfer/issues/21) provided with the solution by [paslandau](https://github.com/paslandau) .

As I've spent the better part of the day to make this work, here is the quick guide of what worked for me:

1. Regards,As I've spent the better part of the day to make this work, here is the quick guide of what worked for me:

Create a service account in Project-A at

`https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?orgonly=true&project=Project-A`

If you already have a service account, you can find its corresponding project id in its json keyfile

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "Project-A",
...
```

2. Activate the Big Query Transfer API for the project you want to create the transfer job at ( Project-B) via

   https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com?project=
3. Add the service account from step 1 to Project-B with Role "Big Query Admin" via https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=Project-B
4. Try to create a transfer job via API (i.e. "from your code"). This will trigger the error mentioned in the titel - which will also include the auto-generated transfer service service account of Project-B, e.g.

```
400 P4 service account needs iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission. Running the following command may resolve this error: gcloud projects  add-iam-policy-binding <PROJECT_ID> --member='serviceAccount:service-<PROJECT_NUMBER>@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
```

Copy the name of the tranfer service account, e.g.

5. Add the transfer service account to Project-A with the role "Service Account Token Creator" via

   https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam?project=Project-A
6. Re-run the creation of the transfer service job as in step 4. It should now succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, but while creating a single scheduled query. It turned out, the problem was me taking the liberty of changing **data_source_id** value into some custom string. After reverting to "scheduled_query" string, as it is provided in available examples, it worked. I believe the solution provided above deals with a different problem (IAM), which can be somewhat simplified by using explicit service account with BigQuery Admin role applied (**service_account_name** TF argument), after enabling bigquerydatatransfer API.